# Delete item from db using id from route javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, http, mongoose, routes

I have a mongodb database of LivingArea objects. I want to remove an object from the db using its id as following:

```
'use strict';

exports = module.exports = ( LivingAreaModel ) => {
    return function* (id) {
        let h = this.request.header,
            b = this.request.body,
            rec = yield LivingAreaModel.findById( {
              _id: id
            } ).remove().exec();
        this.success( {
            livingAreas: rec
        } );
    };
};

exports[ '@singleton' ] = true;
exports[ '@require' ] = [
    'model/livingAreaModel'
];
```

I use a route as following:

```
{
    "method": "delete",
    "path": "/livingarea/delete/:id",
    "handler": "handlers/livingarea/remove.js",
    "validate": [ {
      "param": "id",
      "type": "body",
      "validators": [
        "notEmpty",
        "isString"
      ]
    }]
  }
```

But when I make the call like this: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/livingarea/delete/5783c4da66ac31c814911400 
using the id of one object from the db, i receive the error:

```
{"status":"error","error":{"code":400,"msg":"id is empty"}}
```

Where could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the item not deleted?

Comment: no, it is not. that's why i receive the error, i think

Comment: Have you checked if it has not already been deleted in some previous request by accessing mongodb on terminal?

Comment: yes. the object is still there

Comment: Can you console `id` inside `function* (id)`? is it having value?

Comment: @Shrabanee ive made this change                                                     'rec = yield LivingAreaModel.findById( {
                _id: id
            } ).exec();
        console.log( id );
        yield rec.remove();' but i have the same result, nothing is printed, except [DELETE] /livingarea/delete/5783c4da66ac31c814911400 --> 400 [Bad Request: id is empty]

Comment: even if i try to print a string, nothing happens. so the problem seems to be somewhere here, with the js code

Comment: Add console before the find as error is while doing find. You have line starting with `let`, add before that and check. I think `id` is empty.

Comment: tried. but nothing happens :(

Comment: 'id' is empty or it is printing value? If it is empty then there something wrong in your code.

Comment: no. nothing is printed. not even a string alone, like "foo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer. The method `findById` requires an id, and not an object. More, the route has to look like that:

```
{
    "method": "delete",
    "path": "/livingarea/delete/:id",
    "handler": "handlers/livingarea/remove.js"
  }
```